# How to set a scoreboard that senses a certain item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I want to make a scoreboard that makes it so when you hold a certain item it changes to 1 and when you're not holding it the score becomes 0 again?

Answer (score 0):

Watch the first part of this video:

He does the exact thing you want with a snowball named Grenade, so you should be able to do the same thing.

**Step 1:**

```
/scoreboard objectives add holditem dummy
```

*`holditem` can be called anything, you just need to recall the objective.

**Step 2:**

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar holditem
```

*This is to actually see your "score". I don't believe this is necessary.

**Step 3:**

Place a repeating, always-active command block with this command:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_holditem_min=1] holditem 0
```

*This is to set the score of anyone who is not holding the item to 0

**Step 4:**

Place next to the repeating command block, a chain command block set to always active. Make sure the repeating arrow is pointed towards the chain command block. Type this command:

```
/scoreboard players set @a holditem 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:item_name"}}
```

*This is to set the score of anyone holding the item to 1

---

Step 3 uses an active, repeating command block to constantly update your score to 0 if you aren't holding the item.

Step 4 uses an active chain command block to constantly update your score to 1 if you are holding the item. It constantly updates because it is chained after the repeating command block, so every time the repeating command block updates, the chain one does so as well.

Because the chain is after the repeating command block, it will always override the score to 1 if the item is being held.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. it's best to summarize the key points of the link you have posted in the event that the link is unavailable